# matrix of POSIXct time intervals

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have the following data set which I would like to sum by `end.station.id` and convert into a matrix  of 317 rows and 72 columns

```
> sapply(df, class)
$end.station.id
[1] "integer"

$stoptime
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$interval
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

> dim(df)
[1] 8256    3
> length(unique(df$end.station.id))
[1] 317
> length(unique(df$interval))
[1] 72
> head(df)
      end.station.id            stoptime            interval
14785            437 2014-08-18 21:08:36 2014-08-18 21:00:00
16980            406 2014-08-18 20:34:22 2014-08-18 20:30:00
20200            372 2014-08-18 22:53:33 2014-08-18 22:50:00
20935           2000 2014-08-18 22:43:18 2014-08-18 22:40:00
22610            499 2014-08-18 20:51:28 2014-08-18 20:50:00
22678            401 2014-08-18 20:05:54 2014-08-18 20:00:00
```

I have been unable to do this using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
> matrix % 
+   group_by(end.station.id, interval)%>%
+   summarise(sum = nrow) %>%
+   spread(end.station.id, nrow)
Error: not a vector
```

I have thought of assigning a unique integer to each interval but because it is in POSIXct format, the data is lost when I try to extract the column `interval` and order it with order(x, decreasing = FALSE)

In the end, the outcome should resemble a matrix like this, though filled with the sum per interval per station.

```
> head(m)
  station_id 2014-08-18 20:00:00 2014-08-18 20:10:00 2014-08-18 20:20:00
1        302                   0                   0                   0
2        487                   0                   0                   0
3        218                   0                   0                   0
4        465                   0                   0                   0
5        160                   0                   0                   0
6        291                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 20:30:00 2014-08-18 20:40:00 2014-08-18 20:50:00 2014-08-18 21:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 21:10:00 2014-08-18 21:20:00 2014-08-18 21:30:00 2014-08-18 21:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 21:50:00 2014-08-18 22:00:00 2014-08-18 22:10:00 2014-08-18 22:20:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 22:30:00 2014-08-18 22:40:00 2014-08-18 22:50:00 2014-08-18 23:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 23:10:00 2014-08-18 23:20:00 2014-08-18 23:30:00 2014-08-18 23:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 23:50:00 2014-08-19 00:00:00 2014-08-19 00:10:00 2014-08-19 00:20:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 00:30:00 2014-08-19 00:40:00 2014-08-19 00:50:00 2014-08-19 01:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 01:10:00 2014-08-19 01:20:00 2014-08-19 01:30:00 2014-08-19 01:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 01:50:00 2014-08-19 02:00:00 2014-08-19 02:10:00 2014-08-19 02:20:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 02:30:00 2014-08-19 02:40:00 2014-08-19 02:50:00 2014-08-19 03:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 03:10:00 2014-08-19 03:20:00 2014-08-19 03:30:00 2014-08-19 03:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 03:50:00 2014-08-19 04:00:00 2014-08-19 04:10:00 2014-08-19 04:20:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 04:30:00 2014-08-19 04:40:00 2014-08-19 04:50:00 2014-08-19 05:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 05:10:00 2014-08-19 05:20:00 2014-08-19 05:30:00 2014-08-19 05:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 05:50:00 2014-08-19 06:00:00 2014-08-19 06:10:00 2014-08-19 06:20:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 06:30:00 2014-08-19 06:40:00 2014-08-19 06:50:00 2014-08-19 07:00:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 07:10:00 2014-08-19 07:20:00 2014-08-19 07:30:00 2014-08-19 07:40:00
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0
4                   0                   0                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   0                   0                   0                   0
  2014-08-19 07:50:00
1                   0
2                   0
3                   0
4                   0
5                   0
6                   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `summarize(sum = nrow)` to `summarize(sum = n())` and line `spread(end.station.id, nrow)` to `spread(end.station.id, sum)`.

Finally, transpose the results if you want the intevals on the top with `t()`.

Comment: when I do so I receive the following error: `Error: Value column 'nrow' does not exist in input.`